# Get Textblock in WPF to update using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I just started playing around with WPF using MVVM and encountered a problem.

I want to create a simple program which takes a list of firstnames and surnames and puts together a random name. Everything works except that the name is not shown in the application window.

The button-command is correctly delegated to my function and the PropertyChanged Event is raised when I debug.

My code looks like this:

**ViewModel:**

```
class NamePicker: ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get{return  _name;}
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Name");
        }
    }

    public ICommand CreateNameCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(CreateName); }
    }

    public void CreateName()
    {
        Random rnd =new Random();
        Name = randomNames.firstName[rnd.Next(0, randomNames.firstName.Length - 1)] + " "
                + randomNames.surName[rnd.Next(0, randomNames.surName.Length - 1)];
    }

}
```

**ObservableObject:**

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_Beispiel"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MVVM_Beispiel.ViewModels" x:Class="MVVM_Beispiel.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding CreateNameCommand}" Content="Name ausgeben" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,292,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112">
        <Button.DataContext>
            <ViewModels:NamePicker/>
        </Button.DataContext>
    </Button>
    <Label Content="Namensgenerator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="202,10,0,0" Width="112"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="183" Margin="140,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="244" Source="/MVVM-Beispiel;component/img/007.jpg"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="140,251,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="244">
        <TextBlock.DataContext>
            <ViewModels:NamePicker/>
        </TextBlock.DataContext>
    </TextBlock>

</Grid>
```

**DelegateCommand:**

```
  public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So what exactly am I missing that the TextBlock doesn't show the current generated name? I read some tutorials but those don't go into detail about everything and it seems like I should find a good book about MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different instances of `NamePicker`: first in `Button` and second one in `TextBlock`. So `Name` is changed only in first one. Remove all this stuff:

```
<Button.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:NamePicker/>
</Button.DataContext>

<TextBlock.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:NamePicker/>
</TextBlock.DataContext>
```

and set one view model to entire window:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:NamePicker/>
</Window.DataContext>
```